# What does the special button do?

Tags: super-blood-hockey

In Super Blood Hockey what does the special button do? I see it and have tried everything but there doesn't seem to be any use.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special button is reserved for future gameplay elements in upcoming challenge mode scenarios. As of now it does not perform any function.